# Can I publish a workkflow on sharepoint 2013 without using visio professional 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, visio

I have Sharepoint designer 2013, i am working on a workflow that is already build by the company who setup-ed the initial step of sharepoint 2013. When i came i connected to the site, i can see the workflow, edit it with the text-base designer, and can save. But when i get to publish the workflow, sharepoint designer tries to open visio 2010, which is not compatible with the sharepoint 2013. what i need to know if i have to buy the visio professional 2013 to be able to publish the workflow changes or there is another way.

Comment: I wondered that you must usw visio. Can you usw The Trial for this? Maybe in a vm?

Answer (score 0):

Are you working SP 2013 online or SP 2013 server. Because I have created a workflow and published using SPD 2013 in SP 2013 online from text based designer.